# Node - Connect Node Express to Postgres Running In Docker Container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I have a Node project running with Express.

I have a docker-compose.yml file with my Postgres database contained defined -

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: 'postgres:12'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=12345
      - POSTGRES_DB=testdb
    volumes:
      - pgdata1:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  pgdata1: {}
```

I do not want to run my Node Express server in a docker container, but I do want it to be able to connect to my Postgres database in the docker container.  I am running this on a Mac.  When I start up my Node Express server locally, using Sequelize to connect to the Postgres database, I am unsuccessful.  Is there a way to do this without putting my Node Express server in a Docker container and without hardcoding my local IP address?

server.js file below -

```
import * as express from "express";
import { sequelize } from "./util/database";

const PORT = process.env.STAGE === "local" ? 8080 : 80;
const HOST = "0.0.0.0";

const app = express();

app.get("/", (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.status(200).send("hello world!");
});

app.get("/ping", (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.status(200).send("pong");
});

app.get("/healthy", (req: any, res: any) => {
  res.status(200).send("healthy");
});

const start = async () => {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });

    app.listen(PORT, HOST);

    console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

start();
```

utils/database.ts file below -

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize-typescript";

export const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
  username: process.env.PGUSER,
  password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
  host: process.env.PGHOST,
  dialect: "postgres",
  models: [],
});
```

I removed the models in the models array since that is not relevant to my question.

I first run `docker compose build` and then run `docker compose up -d db` and then `yarn start`

Comment: Did you read the part "Database Configuration" on the [Docker Hub page for Postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)? It explains how you need to configure the Postgres server to allow it to accept incoming TCP connections (by default, Postgres only listens to a Unix domain socket, which will exist inside the Docker container and hence not be accessible from the outside).

Answer (score 0):

In you application you have to connect to 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

Using 0.0.0.0 is just for opening a listening port on all available IPs.

Comment: How do you conclude they are connecting to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: I saw HOST="0.0.0.0" and thought they use that for database connection.